# How to load a bootstrap datetime picker in a modal form in django?

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker

I am trying to load a datetime picker widget in a modal form, therefore I have written this in my forms.py :

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        widgets = {'target_year': BootstrapDateInput()}
```

This loads a widget in my modal form, but when I click the widget it does not work.
Can anyone help me to load this ([Bootstrap Datetime Picker](http://www.malot.fr/bootstrap-datetimepicker/)) widget in my modal form?

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, but reading docs, code should look like ...

... in django modelForm:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        widgets = { 
           'target_year': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'BSdatetimepicker',}), 
                   }
```

... in django template:

```
$('.BSdatetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    format: 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii'   //set right mask
});
```